# ajaxrequest.open getting cancelled by window.location.href

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

OK here's what I've got. I have this voting system where you click a button and it sends a text field to a php script using ajaxrequest.open(). After it sends the data to the php script I want it to load a new page. Here's what I have (condensed version)

```
var mytext = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "vote.php?mytext="+mytext, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
window.location.href = "thanksforvoting.htm";
```

So it sends the text field to vote.php - which works only if i take out the window.location.href line. As long as that line is in, it won't do the ajaxrequest. I assume maybe it's cancelling out because it's loading another page.

I thought maybe I could just use a php 'header' command but that doesn't seem to work. It's not taking me to the page. The script above takes me to the page, but it doesn't get to the php script. If I take out the window.location.href the php script runs but it obviously doesn't take me to the page.

Comment: You could wait for AJAX to complete and then change window location.

Comment: Tell the header error.

Comment: You could also just POST the vote and load a new page, would be the most straightforward thing to do

Answer (score 1):

Since ajax request are made asynchronously, you need to use a callback, otherwise the redirect will occur before the request is complete. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
var mytext = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = callback;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "vote.php?mytext=" + encodeURIComponent(mytext), true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 

function callback() {
   if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4 && ajaxRequest.status === 200) {
      window.location.href = "thanksforvoting.htm";
   }
}
```

MDN has a good [getting started guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) on Ajax.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I am very new to javascript/ajax and this is the only thing I need to work so I probably won't learn much. I can put the callback function inside the same <script> tag, right? I just put yours at the end of my last } bracket. I tried it inside it's own <script> tag as well and it didn't work. Is there something the vote.php file needs to specifically do to let ajaxy know it's completed? I'm also doing this on a windows server, if that has any bearing on the result.

Comment: @user2180748 The scripts can reside within the same `<script>` tag, that is no problem. Does the vote get sent to the server? The server have to return a HTTP 200 status code for this to work. Do you know if it does so? You can inspect the network traffic in the developer tools of your browser, to see what is actually sent to the server, and what the server response is.

Comment: @user2180748 I just realized that you didn't URI-encode whatever value you are reading from that element. Depending on what the value is, that might not be needed, but better safe than sorry. If you replace your Ajax-code with my complete example above, does it work then?